# Excel Macro to concatenate multiple rows from Column B per ID rows in Column A with newlines

Tags: function, excel, xls, vba

This problem is in an Excel .xls file.

**Simplest Use Case:**

Column A has one row.
Column B has 5 rows.
The 5 rows in Column B need to be merged into one row, delimited by newlines.

I have a huge .xls document where there are a ton of IDs in column A.
There are on average anywhere from 3 to 10 rows that belong to each column A row.

How to know which Column B rows belong to which Column A?
By the positioning of the cells.
One Column A row may have 5 Column B rows to the right of it.

I don't have any VBA experience.
I have looked around for macros and functions but haven't had any luck finding anything that matches this problem.

Edit:
I am now trying to figure out how to get the script to ignore rows that have a one-to-one mapping between column A and column B.

Edit again - 06-20-2012:
Now that I can attach images, here is a screenshot of an image for what I'm trying to get. 
The rows for Brian and Mark should be ignored, while Scott and Tim get their values copied over.

[image: results that I'm looking for]

Edit:
Unmerging column A, using the code that Andy supplied, and then using this VB script afterwards does the trick:

> Sub mergeA()
>    For i = 2 To Cells(65535, 1).End(xlUp).Row
>    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then Range(Cells(i - 1, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Merge
>    Next
>   End Sub

That VB script puts the cells in column A back together
I didn't make the script, it came from this web page:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=601304

Comment: might we see a sample of what you mean concerning the layout? Even if the data is not real

Comment: Can we assume that there are blank cells between each ID in column A based on the number of rows in column B (i.e. if "123" is in `A1` and Column B has 3 rows for that ID, then in `A4` we will find the next ID  until we get to a blank row)? Also, do you plan to learn VBA to accomplish your task? Can you show any attempts you've made so far (perhaps you can focus on one part of the problem like how to merge a dynamic number of rows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will transform the data shown on the left to the output on the right:

[image]      [image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Make_Severely_Denormalized()
  Const HEADER_ROWS As Long = 1
  Const OUTPUT_TO_COLUMN As Long = 3
  Const DELIMITER As String = vbNewLine
  Dim A_Range As Range
  Dim B_Range As Range
  Dim A_temp As Range
  Dim B_temp As Range
  Dim B_Cell As Range
  Dim Concat As String

On Error GoTo Whoops
  Set A_Range = Range("A1").Offset(HEADER_ROWS)
  Do While Not A_Range Is Nothing
    Set B_Range = A_Range.Offset(0, 1)

    ' some helper ranges
    If A_Range.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
      Set A_temp = Range(A_Range, A_Range.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0))
    Else
      Set A_temp = A_Range.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    Set B_temp = Range(B_Range, B_Range.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1)

    ' determine how high "B" is WRT no change in "A"
    Set B_Range = Range(B_Range, B_Range.Resize( _
      Application.Intersect(A_temp, B_temp, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Count))

    ' loop through "B" and build up the string
    Concat = ""
    For Each B_Cell In B_Range
      Concat = Concat & B_Cell.Value & DELIMITER
    Next
    Concat = Left(Concat, Len(Concat) - Len(DELIMITER))

    ' do the needful
    A_Range.Offset(0, OUTPUT_TO_COLUMN - 1).Value = Concat

    ' find the next change in "A"
    If A_Range.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
      Set A_Range = Application.Intersect(A_Range.End(xlDown), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    Else
      Set A_Range = A_Range.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
  Loop
  Exit Sub
Whoops:
  MsgBox (Err & " " & Error)
  Stop
  Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Meta comment: I don't understand why sometimes pasted code has syntax markup and other times not? This one, unfortunately, does not.

Comment: The script you put together works for everything except for the use case when there is a one-to-one scenario between column A and column B where both columns each have one row istead of the case where column B has multiple rows per column A. Edit: I'll start picking apart the script to see if i can modify it for that use case. And by the way, your script is greatly appreciated Andy. It puts me right next to where i need to be.

Comment: Right you are. There were bad assumptions in `' some helper ranges` and `find the next change in "A"`. I edited the answer to fix those bugs.

Comment: The script changes made it to where only the first line from column B was copied over. I posted a pic of what I'm looking for in the question above. I know Java, but the syntax and Excel API from VB is killing me when I'm trying to understand it. Thank you for what you brought up so far.

Comment: From your example it looks like column A has merged cells. This complicates things. If possible, unmerging cells in column A will make the code work as advertised (tested using your example). The requirement to skip 1:1 mappings is an easy fix: in the `' some helper ranges` segment, cut out `Else` through `End If` and paste further down, just below `' find the next change in "A"`. Also you can change the `DELIMITER` constant to `" "` (space) to match your sample output exactly.

Comment: -@andy holaday
Thank you Andy! I went ahead an unmerged column A, ran your script, then merged column A back again with the script I posted in my question. I read that cell merging is something dirty that VB coders usually try to stay away from. For the application using this data, the merged cells are necessary. Problem solved.